# What's are the differences between @dynamic and @synthesize?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

From the docs I was reading that @dynamic creates the accessor methods at runtime, while @synthesize will create the accessors at build time.

So let me guess: @dynamic saves some memory and code is kept smaller in memory pages? or what? and what other differences are there between these?

Would it be ok to say: "It's always a good idea to use @dynamic rather than @synthesize"? I mean... if that saves really memory, why not?

But I guess @dynamic has some disadvantage over @synthesize, otherwise everyone would just use @dynamic. So what's the drawbacks?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.  dynamic properties don't get generated automatically.  `@dynamic` properties marker indicates to the compiler that **you** will provide the accessor and setters somehow:

From [Objective-C Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> `@dynamic`
>
> You use the `@dynamic` keyword to tell the compiler that you will fulfill the API contract implied by a property either by providing method implementations directly or at runtime using other mechanisms such as dynamic loading of code or dynamic method resolution.

Answer (score 7):

No, `@dynamic` says the implementations will be provided at runtime. `@synthesize` tells the compiler to create the implementations for you. You would use `@dynamic` with, for example, Core Data, which generates property implementations at runtime. If you don't use either, the compiler assumes you will provide the implementations.

Answer (score 2):

No, @dynamic will not get you any memory/code size advantages